# on printing board in the second case and third it prints the new matrix?

Tags: java

on printing boardcopy why is it printing newboard?though its the copy of board, even on printing board in place of boardcopy its printing newboard only,where the data of board got exchanged by newboard?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MagicTrick {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int board[][]=new int[4][4];
        int boardcopy[][]=new int[4][4];
        boardcopy=board;
        int k=1;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//initializing first board
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            board[i][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
    }

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input");
    int testcse=sc.nextInt();

    /*for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing first board
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            System.out.print(boardcopy[i][j]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println();   
    }*/
    int case1=sc.nextInt();//taking first case
    case1--;



    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing first board
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            System.out.print(board[i][j]+" ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    int case1extend=sc.nextInt();                   //asking for second case


    int newboard[][];
    newboard=board;
    /*System.out.println("tanu");
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing first board
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            System.out.print(board[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }*/

    int buffer;

        for(int z=0;z<4;z++){                       //making newboard
            /*buffer=board[j][j];

                                                    newboard[j][j]=newboard[case1][j];
                                                    newboard[case1][j]=buffer;*/
            if(z==2){
            buffer=newboard[2][2];
            newboard[2][2]=newboard[1][1];
            newboard[1][1]=buffer;
            }
            else{
            buffer=newboard[z][2];
            newboard[z][2]=newboard[case1][z];
            newboard[case1][z]=buffer;
            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){                       //printing firstextended board
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                System.out.print(newboard[i][j]+" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
        }






        int case2=sc.nextInt();
        case2--;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing second board
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                System.out.print(boardcopy[i][j]+" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }
        int case2extend=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing first board
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                System.out.print(boardcopy[i][j]+" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }




        int case3=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing first board
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                System.out.print(boardcopy[i][j]+" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }

        int case3extend=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//printing first board
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                System.out.print(boardcopy[i][j]+" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }
        System.out.println("Output");

        System.out.println("Case #1:"+boardcopy[case1][case2]);
        System.out.println("Case #2:"+"Bad magician!");
        System.out.println("Case #3:"+"Volunteer cheated!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little what you want to achieve?

Comment: plese run my code, its not printing boardcopy matrix instead newboard matrix ,i mean matrix boardcopy is same as board but its printing the contents of newboard matrix why?